# Blob Stream as Input Binding in Azure Function uses which LocationMode to get input stream

Tags: azure, azure-functions, azure-blob-storage

I am using Blob as input binding to get the blob stream as input and then doing processing on this stream text. For disaster recovery, I need to mention LocationMode (Microsoft.Azure.Storage.RetryPolicies) as "PrimaryThenSecondary" while function is getting input stream. What is the by default LocationMode in this case and how to change it.

Below is how Blob input binding is being used-

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
        public async Task RunAsync(
            [EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
            [Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")]Stream input,
            [Table("TableName", Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")]CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
          //Some code

          //To get the data in blob
          StreamReader streamReader = new StreamReader(input);
          string blobData = await streamReader.ReadToEndAsync();
        }
```

One way I see of controlling this is - get the CloudBlockBlob instead of stream as input

```
[FunctionName("FunctionName")]
        public async Task RunAsync(
            [EventGridTrigger]EventGridEvent eventGridEvent,
            [Blob("{data.url}", FileAccess.Read, Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")]CloudBlockBlob input,
            [Table("TableName", Connection = "BlobStorageConnectionString")]CloudTable cloudTable,
            ILogger log)
        {
          //Some code to get the stream using 
          // Task DownloadToFileAsync(string path, FileMode mode, AccessCondition accessCondition, BlobRequestOptions options, OperationContext operationContext);
        }
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> What is the by default LocationMode in this case and how to change it.

You could use [`getLocationMode`](https://azure.github.io/azure-storage-java/com/microsoft/azure/storage/RequestOptions.html#getLocationMode(com.microsoft.azure.storage.LocationMode)) to get the default location mode for this request.

And set the location mode of the request with [`BlobRequestOptions.LocationMode`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.blob.blobrequestoptions.locationmode?view=azure-dotnet-legacy) Property.

```
locationModeRequestOptions = new BlobRequestOptions() { LocationMode = RetryPolicies.LocationMode.PrimaryThenSecondary };
byteCount = blob.DownloadToByteArray(destinationArray, index: 0, accessCondition: null, options: locationModeRequestOptions);
```

The `LocationMode` contains `PrimaryOnly`, `PrimaryThenSecondary`, `SecondaryOnly`and  `SecondaryThenPrimary`. For more details, you could refer to this [article](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.azure.storage.retrypolicies.locationmode?view=azure-dotnet-legacy).

Comment: Right.. but for this i need to take CloudBlockBlob as the input binding in function. What happens if i use Stream as input binding. In case of stream, we do not download the blob text explicitly, it automatically gets downloaded and is passed on as stream. But I want to know what LocationMode is used when this stream is passed as input to function. Reason for ask- Want to make sure that if primary region is down, still we are getting the stream from blob

Comment: For stream, it seems that you could not set the location mode for stream.

Comment: correct.. we cannot set. But what location mode is being used in backend when we use stream?

Comment: It seems that design by default and I could not find any document to get it.